# NDSolve diffusion equation over/underdetermined

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I have a feeling the solution to my problem is very simple… but my knowledge of differential equations is pretty weak.

I am trying to solve a scalar diffusion equation (used in NMR spectroscopy, but from what I understand, modeled after heat and Fickian diffusion). I've tried following model equations, but whenever I ask Mathematica to evaluate, it returns the original equation. What am I missing here?

Here is my code:

```
With[{Dif = 2300, pde = D[u[t, r], t] == Dif/r*D[u[t, r]*r, r, r] - 
 1/(0.0945 E^(0.000212+0.4077r))*(u[t, r]+1.2004)}, 
 soln = NDSolve[{pde, u[0, r] == 0, Derivative[0, 1][u][t, 0] == 0, 
 Limit[u[t, r], r -> \[Infinity]] == 0}, u, {t, 0, 10}, {r, 0, 500}]]
```

Upon evaluation, it returns an error stating that the equation is "overdetermined". Removing a single one of the 3 boundary conditions results in an "underdetermined" error.

Is this possible to solve using NDSolve, or do I need to break down the equation?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: As it stands, you need to define `Dif` for a start. You also have a boundary condition that is outside the region that you are trying to integrate in. I believe you will have to define the large `r` part of `u` explicitly. ie. `u[t,500]==1/500` or however you understand the function behaves in the large `r` limit. You will also have to set the boundary conditions away from `r=0` as the equation looks to be singular there.

Comment: Sorry, I have defined `Dif=2300` in an earlier cell… In all of my fooling about, I forgot to put it into the `With` statement. Fixed now.

Comment: Expanding upon comment of @JonathanShock.

The proper condition for $r=500$ is $u(t,500)=0$. I think the solution is tending to zero as $r\to \infty$ at least exponentially. 

Also one has to move a bit from the boundary $r=0$ since there is a singularity in the equation's coefficients and `NDSolve` gives messages 

> Power::infy: "Infinite expression 1/0. encountered."

Here the condition for `r=0` is changed on condition for `r=10^-8`.

Comment: With[{Dif = 2300}, 
     pde = D[u[t, r], t] == 
       Dif/r*D[u[t, r]*r, r, r] - 
        1/(0.0945 E^(0.000212 + 0.4077 r))*(u[t, r] + 1.2004); 
     soln = NDSolve[{pde, u[0, r] == 0, 
        Derivative[0, 1][u][t, 10^-8] == 0, u[t, 500] == 0}, 
       u, {t, 0, 10}, {r, 10^-8, 500}]]

Comment: @Andrew, that works! Should've thought to change the limit off zero… Mathematica seems so smart sometimes, I am sometimes surprised by the things that can trip it up. Now, is there a way to mark the question as answered by one of the comments, or does it have to be a proper "answer" response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Andrew](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/306/andrew) stated above, changing the lower limit to something non-zero takes care of the problem.

The following code gives a speedy answer:

```
With[{Dif = 2300}, pde = D[u[t, r], t] == Dif/r*D[u[t, r]*r, r, r] - 
 1/(0.0945 E^(0.000212 + 0.4077 r))*(u[t, r] + 1.2004); 
 soln = NDSolve[{pde, u[0, r] == 0, Derivative[0, 1][u][t, 10^-8] == 0, 
 u[t, 500] == 0}, u, {t, 0, 10}, {r, 10^-8, 500}]]
```