# Why do I have to perform a second ReplaceAll in this InterpolatingFunction?

Tags: plotting, interpolation

I have an InterpolatingFunction that I'd like to plot, and I wonder why I have to perform a `ReplaceAll` on the following function:

```
Plot[Evaluate[IIz[r, t] /. soln] /. t -> 5, {r, 0, 490}, PlotRange -> {{0, 
 490}, {.000015, -.00035}}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]`
```

`soln` is the solution to a differential diffusion equation given by Mathematica (v. 9.0.1) as

```
{{IIz[r,t]->InterpolatingFunction[{{1.*10^-8,490.5},{0.,10.}},<>][r,t]}}[r, 
 t]}}
```

When I plot the 3D solution, there is no problem in using

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[IIz[r, t] /. soln], {r, 0, 490}, {t, 0, 10},   PlotRange -> 
 {{0, 490}, {0, 10}, {.000015, -.00035}},   AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

and I would think that all I'd need to do to plot this in terms of a fixed `t` would be to replace `t` with a constant like so:

```
Plot[Evaluate[IIz[r, 5] /. soln] , {r, 0, 490},   PlotRange -> {{0, 490}, 
 {.000015, -.00035}}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]`
```

However, when I input that, I get a blank plot… What gives?

For the original differential equation, see this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25153/ndsolve-diffusion-equation-over-underdetermined).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will work as you expect if you get the solution in a form like

```
IIz ->InterpolatingFunction[...
```

and not like

```
IIz[r,t] -> ...
```

since in the second case you have to have the explicit t, not 5, in order for the match to succeed.

Comment: I didn't even realize that specification was unnecessary… Thank you for the clarification, and as you, say, it works perfectly. Is there any advantage to getting the solution in the original form rather than `IIz[r,t]`?